# Passing a variable instead of target cell to Solver in VBA

Tags: vba, solver

i'm writing a procedure where i need to call a sub which runs the solver on each step of a loop. I used a target cell for all solutions that i've built previously, however, i'd like to know whether its possible to pass a variable, which is a function of the variables the solver needs to evaluate?
What i mean is something like this:

say x is my variable i'm trying to maximize, where x is a function of some variables (y1,y2,...,yn)
Y1,y2,...,yn are also the solution, which my solver should return that maximizes my x.

I know how to do it if the fucntion for x is explicitly written in a cell (to which i can reference the target cell in the solver) and my other variables y1,y2,..yn are entries in a range of cells.

What i'm looking for is a piece of code where x and y1,y2,...,yn are generated as an array inside VBA? Does anyone know whether this is possible?

So far, i solved this for y1,y2,..,yn, however, i'm not sure how to update my variable x each time the solver tries another solution to maximize x...
Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks a lot for your help, any comments are appreciated!

Comment: I don't think solver can be used this way - you need to have formulas to update x as Solver changes your y values.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that's what I was afraid of. Seems I need to build my own optimizer for this?

Comment: If you really can't use a worksheet, then yes.  That's a pretty big task though.

Comment: OK, thanks again. I have some hard constraints as well and several variables that maximize x as in the question. Which algorithms can I use to solve this? I already have a Nelder Mead for soft constraints but  it doesn't really address my constraints properly that's why I tried the solver..

Comment: Sorry I can't help there - I have used Solver with VBA in the past but have no idea how it does what it does.